# Family/Link for averaged categorical data

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have categorical data coded 0/1 at the observation level. I have averaged these values across trials, obtaining a probability value between 0 and 1.

I am running GLME's in R using `family = Gamma(link = identity)` (continuous) and `family = binomial(link = logit)` within the models, however for the averaged categorical data I am struggling.

Some averages have a value of 0, meaning I cannot use the gamma family/identity link; whereas since we have more than 2 unique values, we cannot use the binomial family/logit link.

I am aware I *could* run LME's without specifying the family/link, however, I am tied to running GLME's due to pre-registration processes linked with the data.

Here's an example of the data and code that I am using

```
datafile <- structure(list(
  depvar= c("0.00000000", "0.02197802", "0.37948718", "0.00000000", "0.15789474",  "0.00000000", "0.00000000", "0.18181818", "0.07142857", "0.00000000", "0.06060606", "0.94366197"), 
  window = c("window", "window", "window", "nowindow", "nowindow", "nowindow", "window", "window", "window", "nowindow", "nowindow", "nowindow"),
  trial_sound = c("quiet", "standard", "deviant", "quiet", "standard", "deviant", "quiet", "standard", "deviant", "quiet", "standard", "deviant"),
item = c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
pp = c (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
  .Names = c("depvar","window", "trial_sound", "item", "pp"),
  row.names = c(NA, -12L),
  class = "data.frame")
summary(datafile)
```

```
depvar.glmer1 = glmer(depvar ~ window*trial_sound + (1+ window*trial_sound|pp) + 
(1+ window*trial_sound|item),control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=20000)),
 data = datafile, family= Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

Any advice and references/resources that may help me would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way to handle these data would be as binomial with the `weights` argument specifying the number of trials per observation.  For example, say we have `depvar = c(1/5, 2/6, 0/3, 7/7)` (= `c(0.2, 0.3333, 0, 1)` and `ntrial = c(5, 6, 3, 7)`, then we would fit the model

```r
glmer(depvar ~ ..., weights = ntrial, family = binomial, ...)
```

(the logit link is the default for the binomial family). This does everything you want:

- handles values that are exactly 0 and 1
- naturally bounded at 0/1, like the data

Comment: thank you! apologies that I am continuing this thread which should be on Stack Exchange, but any idea why I am getting an error of "response is constant"?

Comment: don't know offhand. In the example you gave your depvar is `character` - you'd have to convert it to numeric. (I did get "response must be numeric or factor" when I try `glmer` with a character response variable though ...) Do you get the same error with `lmer()` (in which case it would have something to do with data processing, e.g. something is getting converted to NA and throwing out most of your data ... ?)  Can you edit your question to include `summary(datafile)` ?

Comment: No - lmer runs without initial error. The data in the averaged variables is normally distributed so I wondered if it was an issue with using the glmer function (however, I am tied to the GLME due to preregistering my analyses).

Comment: Are there any other warnings printed? Does it still happen if you simplify the model radically, e.g. `glmer(depvar ~ 1 + (1|pp), data = datafile, weights = ntrial, family = binomial)` ? Any chance you can post a [mcve]?

Comment: No other warnings printed - just the one mentioned as soon as the model begins to run. I will try simplifying the model. In my data, 'depvar' is reclassified as integer - I will amend the example to include this rather than character.  I'll work on an MRE once I check the simplified model - thanks!

Comment: if `depvar` is coerced/converted to an integer it will be rounded down/truncated, so if all the values are between 0 and 1 they will all be rounded to 0. If `depvar` is a value in [0,1), don't convert it to an integer ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254893/discussion-between-s2068-and-ben-bolker).